# How to use Multiple HttpPost methods

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a simple application in MVC4 in which I am displaying data from SQL server compact into a Webgrid which contains Name and Age as a column. I have two buttons for sorting purpose(I know functionality is already there in Webgrid but still for task purpose I am doing that). Then I have edit button beside every row which will help in editing the row, as soon as I click edit button row changes to textbox and edit button is replace with save and cancel button for this purpose I am using JQuery. In controller i have 2 Actionresult method(INDEX & editRow) one will be called when I click for sorting purpose and other will be called when clicked for editing pupose but whenever I am clicking on edit button INDEX is called which asks for button value so its throwing Null Pointer Exception. Please help me in sorting out the problem. Below i m providing my code 
    Thanks In Advance

**Controller Class**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var allEntries = from entry in db.task
                             select entry;
            return View(allEntries.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(String button)
        {
            if (button.Contains("Name"))
            {
            var allSortedEntries=db.task.OrderBy(person => person.Name);
            return View("Index",allSortedEntries.ToList());
            }
            else if (button.Contains("Age"))
            {
                var allSortedEntries = db.task.OrderBy(page => page.Age);
                return View("Index", allSortedEntries.ToList());
            }
               return View(); 

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditRow(Task2 entry)
        {
            var updateentry = db.task.SingleOrDefault(pid => pid.id == entry.id);
            updateentry.id = entry.id;
            updateentry.Name = entry.Name;
            updateentry.Age = entry.Age;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", entry);
        }
```

**Model Class**

```
public class Task2
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@model IList<Task2Sorting.Models.Task2>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/Script/edit.js">
</script>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Name List";
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,

               rowsPerPage: 10);

}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div id="grid">
        @grid.GetHtml(columns: new[]
{

    grid.Column(" ",format:@<text><div class="display-mode">
        <input type="hidden" id="idtxt" value="@item.id"/></div>
        <div class="edit-mode">
            <input type="hidden" id="idhidden" value="@item.id"/></div></text>,canSort:false),
    grid.Column("Name",format:@<text><div class="display-mode">@item.Name</div>
        <div class="edit-mode">
            <input type="text" id="nametxt" value="@item.Name" style="width:80px"/>
        </div></text>,canSort:false),
    grid.Column("Age",format:@<text><div class="display-mode">@item.Age</div>
        <div class="edit-mode">
            <input type="text" id="agetxt" value="@item.Age" style="width:80px"/>
        </div></text>,canSort:false),
    grid.Column("Action ",format:@<text>
        <button class="display-mode" name="editbtn">Edit</button>
        <button class="edit-mode" name="savebtn">Save</button>
        <button class="edit-mode" name="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        </text>,canSort:false),

})
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        @*<button id="sname" value="Name">Sort By Name</button>
        <button id="aname" value="Age">Sort By Age</button>*@
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Sort By Name" id="sname"/>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Sort By Age" id="aname"/>
    </div>
}
```

**JQuery file**

```
$(function () {
    $('.edit-mode').hide();
    $('button[name=editbtn]').click(function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
        tr.find('.edit-mode').toggle();
        tr.find('.display-mode').toggle();
    });

    $('button[name=savebtn]').click(function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
        var Name = tr.find("#nametxt").val();
        var Age = tr.find("#agetxt").val();
        var Id = tr.find("#idhidden").val();
        tr.find("#name").text(Name);
        tr.find("#age").text(Age);
        tr.find('.edit-mode').toggle();
        tr.find('.display-mode').toggle();


        var Task2 =
        {
            "Id": Id,
            "Name": Name,
            "Age": Age
        };
        $.post("/Show/EditRow", Task2)
        {

        }
    });
    $('button[name=cancelbtn]').on('click', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
        tr.find('.edit-mode').toggle();
        tr.find('.display-mode').toggle();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Edit button is actually submitting your form to the server.
Try `return false;` like

```
$('button[name=editbtn]').click(function () {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    tr.find('.edit-mode').toggle();
    tr.find('.display-mode').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

You may face the same issue with Save and Cancel, try `return false;` there as well. It will stop the default browser behavior of posting your form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it worked but I have a doubt here even after specifying the ActionResult for save button it is still going to Index. Because I need to submit the form when I click on the save button so that I get the updated value from the database which I saved. can anyone clarify my doubt about the same.

Comment: Your save functionality uses AJAX which means the DB will be updated without refreshing the page. i.e. You don't have to hit Index to get latest values because the page already has the latest (entered by user). PS if my answer helps you with your original problem then feel free to mark my answer as accepted

Comment: My DB is getting updated but its not getting displayed on the page I have to refresh the page manually to see the updated value. I even tried redirecting to the Index action which fetches all the data but still I got nothing out of it. Is there is anyway you can help me with this.